# Tongue and teeth don't follow the movement when I change the pose, any suggestins on how to fix this?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

[image]

Tongue and teeth don't follow the movement when I change the pose, any suggestins on how to fix this?

Comment: probably wrongly attached to the whole rig, is it parented to something? Or weigt painted and part of the whole body?

Comment: select them in Edit mode, on the right of your Vertex Groups list, click on the dropdown button and choose Remove From All Groups, then assign these vertices to the group they are supposed to be part of (i.e. the group that has the name of the bone that is supposed to control them)

Comment: @moonboots it worked, thanks!

Comment: @MikoCG Yes I had previously joined them to the rest of the body, so I'm sure it had something to do with that, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select them in *Edit* mode, on the right of your *Vertex Groups* list, click on the dropdown button and choose *Remove from All Groups*, then assign these vertices with the *Assign* button to the group they are supposed to be part of (i.e. the group that has the name of the bone that is supposed to control them)

**Example:**
[image: screenshot]
Here the lips are hidden so we can see better the teeth.

When you select one vertex then you can see the groups to which it is assigned in the <kbd>N</kbd>-panel. If you have selected a bunch of verts make sure that one is the active one (highlighted in white) because when you use *Box* or *Lasso* select there will be no active vertice. With <kbd>L</kbd> you can select all linked vertices.

In the screenshot, you can see that the selected vertice of the tooth is incorrectly assigned to the top lip and the nose vertex groups. That is,  these bones have an influence on it.

To fix this, use the drop-down menu and finally assign it to the correct group (*DEF-teeth.top*).