# Rigging effect on wrong object

Tags: rigging

I have this problem with one of my models that I am trying to fix. I tried a lot of options before coming to you all

I design a low poly 3d boots, and I want to parent them to an existing armature - using automatic weights. I am facing a side effect that occur when I try to move one of the boots (using my armature). Instead of deformed only the effected boot it also deformed the other boot.

Things I did:

1. Apply mirror
2. Separate the boots "by loose parts"
3. Ensure no subdivision nor duplicate vertices
4. Assign each of them to an existing armature
5. Assure that the weight painting is not effecting on the other boot
6. Remove duplicate
7. Clear parents
8. Clear vertex groups
9. Reassign each boots to the armature

Nothing helps. I have used this same method with other objects - like glove. Came out perfectly fine.

Hope to hear some new ideas

Thank you

Comment: Can you add your blend file to your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: maybe my answer here will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237997/tongue-and-teeth-dont-follow-the-movement-when-i-change-the-pose-any-suggestin/238000#238000