# Automatic weights problem

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, error

When I try to add bones to an object, and go to automatic weights, the body just falls down and the bones are still in the air then, where the body used to be before clicking with automatic weights. How can I fix this problem?

I have uploaded my file with that problem with eyes and teeth I guess, here [blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/c78707b5c7ea451cae76e84f5d43db66)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you post a couple pics of what's going on please?

Comment: Have you enabled other physics like cloth or softbody, rigid body? A mesh usually doesn't fall down without a reason.

Comment: You don't know how to make a screenshot or how to upload it here? Windows has a program named *Snipping Tools* that can create screenshots. Edit your question and you will see there is a toolbar. One is called "Image" where you can upload images to your question. Blender's physics you can find in the Physics tab on the right side on the screen where all the vertically icons are. It usually also adds a modifier to your mesh. When you're new to Blender check out some tutorials on YT.

Comment: Thanks for the image. Ah, indeed it "falls down". Now I got it. That's because the mesh is rotated and the rotation is not applied.

Comment: You need to apply the scale to the mesh. See my answer below.

Comment: When the eyes and teeth are separate objects (in the outliner) you can select them and parent them to the armature with automatic weights. When they are just loose parts of the body mesh (I understand that they are now) you need to assign them to the vertex group that has the same name as the head bone in edit mode. Remove them from all other groups as described here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237997/tongue-and-teeth-dont-follow-the-movement-when-i-change-the-pose-any-suggestin/238000#238000

Comment: We should make a chat. The number of comments gets a bit high. But you don't have enough reputation for the chat. So here is another comment: The *Remove from All Groups* is hidden in the dropdown menu. I'll update the answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237997/tongue-and-teeth-dont-follow-the-movement-when-i-change-the-pose-any-suggestin/238000#238000. Make sure you have only selected the eyes (`Alt+A`=unselect all),then select one vertice and press `L` to select the eye. Keep the mouse over it, then *Remove from All Groups*,  then *Assign*. Repeat the steps for the teeth

Comment: You can share files here on BSE (https://blend-exchange.com/help). The file won't be deleted. -Or- you can upload it at https://pasteall.org/blend/. Here the file gets deleted after 5 months. And after the upload, you will get a new URL in the browser's address bar. Copy it here, it's the key to access the file. (Going to delete a few of my old comments)

Comment: The file is linked in your question see above! I've edited your question and added the link to your shared file. Just had a look at it and updated my answer. See below.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am beginner in blender so if you don't mind to ask you a question how did you manage to move almost every part of the mesh? Is it with some bones or how? Does it already have some bones, are they that dots you were talking about?  Also, I have to do the animation exactly on this mesh, so I need to ask you too is it possible to do an animation on it? And I have to ask you too, why the mesh lost its color? Thank you

Comment: And is it possible to fix all these problems on this mesh?

Comment: You're welcome. That's too many questions to answer here. If you like send a message at https://blenderartists.org. My name is JoeBlunder there.

Comment: Okay, I have entered on that platform and found you but I don't see the option to send you a message, so I created this: https://blenderartists.org/t/problems-with-mesh/1333809?u=glitter_sparkles

Comment: If you could tell me where to send a message or something like that or where to post my answers, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Before you bind the mesh to the armature (parent *With Automatic Weights*) you need to apply the *Rotation* of the mesh. Your character was modeled lying on the floor and then rotated by 90° to get it up. When you bind it to the armature it's reset to the original position on the floor. You need to apply the rotation to tell Blender that the standing pose is the new original position.

Select the mesh in *Object* mode, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > Apply *All Transformations*. This applies *Scale*, *Rotation* and *Location*.

To have everything nice and clean you can do this for the armature, too. Then parent them together.

If some loose parts of the mesh such as the eyes and teeth don't follow the armature then the automatic weights didn't work correctly. This happens often for loose parts. You need to assign them to the head bone manually as described in this question here: [Tongue and teeth don't follow the movement when I change the pose, any suggestins on how to fix this?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237997/tongue-and-teeth-dont-follow-the-movement-when-i-change-the-pose-any-suggestin/238000#238000)

**Update after inspecting the blend file**

There are several problems.

The rig (armature object) is not ideal. Your model is 90 meters tall but all bones are tiny and aligned vertically. I don't know how to fix this easily. The bones for the eye are overlapped by the upper and lower eyelids for example. It's not very comfortable to use and I am not sure if automatic weights work well with these tiny wrong aligned bones. Maybe consider using Rigify to create a new rig?

There are two *Armature* modifiers. Remove the second one to fix the teeth and eyelashes.

Furthermore, the mesh is not aligned properly. You need to move it a bit to the left (←).

For the left eye (on the right side) the vertex group acts weird. Even if you use the *Remove From All Groups* button there are some verts of the right sleeve moving along. I've deleted the group, created a new vertex group with the same name, and assigned all vertices of the eye to the group. Then it worked.

The mesh has a lot of loose parts. Automatic weights don't work very well with loose parts. If you parent the mesh to the armature (*With Automatic Weights*) you will notice that there are problems with the feet. And around the area of the belly/back, there is a hole when the character bends. This can be fixed with a remeshed duplicated dummy model that is used for the automatic weights. Then the weights are transferred back to the original model. This method is described here: [heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/223782/107598) or check [this video](https://youtu.be/j823wSrHJnA).

If you're new to rigging then it might be easier to start with Rigify or a model that is already rigged like the [Rain](https://cloud.blender.org/p/characters/5f04a68bb5f1a2612f7b29da) or [Vincent](https://cloud.blender.org/p/characters/5718a967c379cf04929a4247). Vincent uses BlenRig. If you want to try [BlenRig 6 beta](https://blenderartists.org/t/blenrig-5-public-release/660103/463) for your character model you can get it [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/blenrig-5-public-release/660103/463).

I've done the automatic weights and transferred them, and fixed the eyes. It works except for the legs. It's the bad rig with these tiny bones. It's the dots on the screenshot. It's not a custom shape but tiny sticks:

[image: screenshot]

The mesh has not much geometry for the upper arms, and they bend not very well. The rig has no IK. That's another disadvantage when you want to animate the character.

Blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/6d5634b7e22a4d93abf21dd2713039fb